# What objects should I use for HttpClient programming?

Tags: java, httpclient, httpresponse

I'm trying to write a class that will be able to send requests to servers through URLs and receive responses from the server as well.

I've been researching HttpClient but it seems like there are a lot of different types of HttpClient objects from various users.  I'm not sure which I should use.  I'd prefer to use Apache objects if at all possible.

Requirements:

Must be able to send requests through urls using the get method.  I'd like to use HttpMethod for this.
Must be able to submit a form to either the get or post method.
Must be able to get and store cookies from a response as well as send those cookies in a request header.
The ability to spoof the referrer header would be useful as well.

Some example code of what I'm trying to do:

```
String searchURL = //however I'm generating the search URL
String responeAsString = "";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new MultiThreadedConnectionManager());
client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setConnectionTimeout(30000);
HttpMethod method = new GetMethod(searchURL);

try{
    client.executeMethod(method);
    responseAsString = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
}catch (Exception e){
    //error fixing code
}
```

I'd like to be able to replace responseAsString with an actual HttpResponse object, but I haven't been able to find a resource of where to download a jar file.

If you could include links on where to download the .jar files of the objects you suggest, that would be great.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little overkill but I'd look at the open source project GWT https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/

They have a sample application which does communicate with the server and you could see how it works.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can find a Java HTTP Client comparison at http://oaklandsoftware.com/product_http/compare.html

Your requisites seem basic so they should be supported by any library, except for the last one about the HttpResponse object but using Apache library you can get the body, headers and footers of the response from HttpMethod, this sould be enough.  Other libraries should offer something similar, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks.  I think this is the way I'm going to go.  It seems like the options there are the least intrusive and that's a plus, since I'm trying to replace a module in an existing product with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything u requested with the Apache Default Http Client version 4
you can modify the response string to any valid HTTPResponse object.
you can change all the headers in the request and response, including the referrer header. 
you should only know the header name to be able to replace it.

The library is available at http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/

please make sure you get the version 4.

A guide on how to use it is available at: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/

you can find the list of request and response headers you can use at: first link given by google search for keyword "http response headers" - the wiki article.

Enjoy!!